# Install java plugin in chrome in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, google-chrome, ubuntu

I have installed Oracle Java 7 in my `/home` directory by following steps given [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux) (by just changing the path of installation). But still I cannot see the plugin listed in the `chrome://plugins` tab.

I also cannot see it running in [JavaTester](http://javatester.org) or [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp). I have tried enabling by following steps provided [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Oracle-Java-in-Your-Web-Browsers-on-Ubuntu-Linux) but nothing works.

Some specifications:
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04
output of `java -version`:
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Please comment if anything more is needed for resolving the problem

Comment: Have you checked the linked resource http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Oracle-Java-in-Your-Web-Browsers-on-Ubuntu-Linux that explains how install it in your browser?

Comment: Yes I have tried but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Just pull it from webupd8 servers. Follow the directions at the following link.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Also, this belongs on a different forum. This forum is for programming questions, installing a chrome plugin isn't really what we do. Next time post to the Ubuntu stack exchange located [here](https://askubuntu.com/).